# Cannot load V8 interface assembly. Load failure information for v8-ia32.dll

Tags: c#

Cannot load V8 interface assembly. Load failure information for v8-ia32.dll:
C:\Users\szymarad\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\506fb4ab\b0850f51\assembly\dl3\28a19a82\00b1e3d3_a5add301\v8-ia32.dll: The specified module could not be found
C:\Users\szymarad\source\repos\KTM\Geta-KTM3.0\src\KTM.Web\v8-ia32.dll: The specified module could not be found
C:\Users\szymarad\source\repos\KTM\Geta-KTM3.0\src\KTM.Web\bin\v8-ia32.dll: The specified module could not be found

Also installed 
Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017

I have cleared the temp asp.net folder
cleaned solution
restarted my computer

tried to install microsoft.clearscript but than i get 
 Could not load file or assembly 'ClearScriptV8-32.DLL' or one of its dependencies.

Suggestions?

Comment: It is the 32-bit version of the V8 runtime, fairly unusual for an asp.net deployment since it requires forcing the app pool into 32-bit mode.  Some odds you meant to use v8-ia64.dll.  As-is, you ought to double-check that you installed the correct flavor of the redist.  Navigate to c:\windows\syswow64 and verify that it has msvcp140.dll and vcruntime140.dll

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Have the same issue

Answer (score 14):

The reason ASP .NET looks for that v8-ia32.dll assembly in the bin folder is that by default when you are running a ASP .NET web project, and IIS Express runs at background, it runs in a 32-bit (x86) mode so it would load assemblies or modules in the same mode which are in 32-bit (x86). If you already have installed MS Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017, that is fine but it won't solve the issue.

The **solution** is to install the Nuget package JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8.Native.win-x86 in your ASP .NET project that gives three assemblies after building the ASP .NET project.

Under \bin\x86\ directory:

- ClearScriptV8-32.dll
- v8-base-ia32.dll
- v8-ia32.dll

If you have installed a different package which is the Microsoft.ClearScript only and you do have a JavaScriptEngineSwitcher package, this might cause a trouble but just give it a try to still install package JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8.Native.win-x86 to solve the issue.

For a good documentation you can also refer to Taritsyn's documentation. See https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/issues/409, he gave a detailed instructions to follow and guidelines.

Under the **V8** section of his post he said:

> "In general, usage of the ClearScript.V8 package together with the
>   JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8 is causing errors."

Then he also suggests if you're not sure what to use of the JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8.Native.win, you can install both the 32-bit and 64-bit packages.

> ".NET applications, ASP.NET web applications and sites in 64-bit
>   Windows can run not only in 64-bit processes, but also in 32-bit
>   processes. For correct working of the JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8 in
>   32-bit process need to install the
>   JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8.Native.win-x86 package. If you do not know
>   in which process will run your application or web site, then install
>   both packages."

Hope this helps to solve the issue.

Comment: This worked for me (getting the Nuget package JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8.Native.win-x86 and Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2019).

Comment: @RepellantCoder your solutions works as well for me :)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error and solved it by rebuilding the whole solution:

1. Build -> Clean Solution
2. Delete the NuGet `packages` folder under the solution root directory (eg using Windows Explorer)
3. Build -> Rebuild
4. Build -> Build
5. Ctrl + F5

Some of the steps may not be needed but the main thing is it started working :)

Comment: I had to manually delete my `obj` and `bin` folders.

Answer (score 1):

Switch bitness of IIS Express to x64 in VS project properties or in project file:

```
<Use64BitIISExpress>true</Use64BitIISExpress>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me helped this:
Tools -> Options -> Project and Solutions -> Web Projects -> "Use 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects".

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the website was giving this error on server. The step which solved my issue was to download and install [visual-c-redistributable](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2019) on server.